# Microsoft support for HEIF / HEIC in .NET?

Tags: .net

Does anyone have any information about Microsoft support for this file format within the .NET arena?

It seems like everyone praises the format, but no one is providing programming support, or at least none that I have found.

If any language/development environment (libraries, packages, etc.) is supporting this standard please let me know.

Thank you in advance,
Bill

Comment: You can integrate the cloud converter .net 6 libraries. Please find the API docs from https://cloudconvert.com/.